# Wordpress displays content of my php.ini file on every pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing a real problem that i've never seen before..
I could'nt find any post on this subject on any help forum.
So please help me if you encountered this thing !! :)

Let me explain:
I'm hosting a wordpress site at 1and1.com on a mutualized hosting.
All is up to date (wordpress and all plugins installed)
The problem is that it shows twice the content of my `php.ini` file on the top of every pages of my site.
Here is the text displayed:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 128M
```

It appears just after the BODY opening tag.

I managed to solve the problem once last week by deleting the `php.ini` file but it seems that it has been recreated automatically because the problem appears again today.

EDIT: I found that only php.ini files located in the 2 following directories are displayed:
/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/autoload/params
/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/autoload/vendors
They are directories from the plugin : Visual Composer
It seems to include every files located in that directory without any distinction between .php or any other extension or name.  Is it a normal behavior?

Does anyone has information about this?
Or just a direction to search?

Thank you very much for any idea!

Comment: Is the problem that env variables are printed or that they are printed twice?

Comment: no the problem is that a php.ini file is not meant to be included in a php script and "echoed" in the html code.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to include every files located in that directory without any distinction between .php or any other extension or name. Is it a normal behavior?

As it is stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

I hardly believe in that creators of the plugin would include/require non php files as it would be complete non-sense and could trigger errors, e.g, `Warning`, `Parse error` (e.g. when using .png)

What I suggest is to use `debug_print_backtrace()` to track down the execution of script and modify the problematic scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It is real that js_composer load all files in own autoload folder. If you want to make them open only php files patch is needed. I can provide if needed. Just edit js_composer.php file method loadComponents to check for file extension. It maybe will be fixed in next major release. 4.7, 4.8v